# I would like to override the style a vaadin-dialog web component, position it else than in the middle of the page

Tags: css, overriding, vaadin, styling, lit

{
                          this.DimensionDialogOpened = event.detail.value;
                          //console.log("dialog opened");
                          }
                        
                        }"
                        ${dialogRenderer( () => html
                          `
                          
                            
                              
                            
                          
                           
                          `
                          )}

```
                >
            </vaadin-dialog>
```

I divided the screen into 3 and i expect the dialog to be shown in the right end div,
when someone click on a buttoon

Answer (score 0):

If you want apply style to your component pass style prop to component and set it with the help of styleMap() method from lit.

Comment: to be more precise , i would like to position the shadow dialog relative to a div , but without using top , right , left,  bottom poitioning inside the vaadin-dialog-overlay::part(overlay). and i would like to use it in an alreday existing component